# Broken patches on a road

Tags: vocabulary

[image]

---

Are the broken patches on the road called holes? If not, then what do we call them? What exactly a hole is? One that is from one surface to another?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Those are **potholes**.

> A pothole is a hole in a road surface that results from gradual damage caused by traffic and/or weather ([Cambridge dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/pothole)).

You may have noticed, we can say that those are holes in the road (because a pothole is still a hole). But if you say 
*pothole*, you are just more specific and it may be more natural to say it like that.

Check out the meaning of *hole* [here](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/hole).

Comment: True, this is the first word most native speakers would think of. However, it may be worth noting that, when we think of [potholes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pothole), we usually imagine them on some kind of asphalt or pavement (like [this one](http://mediad.publicbroadcasting.net/p/wvxu/files/styles/medium/public/201301/Pothole-1.jpg)). Nevertheless, I supposed I'd still use _pothole_ to describe the holes in the OP's image.

Answer (score 2):

They could be referred to as **ruts** if they were long and narrow and preferably caused by wheels.

> a deep, narrow mark made in soft ground especially by a wheel ([Cambridge dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/rut)).

Pothole also works as shown by Enguroo's answer:

> "Those are potholes."
>
> A pothole is a hole in a road surface that results from gradual damage caused by traffic and/or weather ([Cambridge dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/pothole)).
>
> You may have noticed, we can say that those are holes in the road (because a pothole is still a hole). But if you say pothole, you are just more specific and it may be more natural to say it like that.
>
> Check out the meaning of hole [here](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/hole)."

Full disclosure, the pothole section is a copy and paste from Enguroo's answer because I find it valid but lacking Rut as an option. I know that the potholes in the OP's image arent ruts but their description could be intending something different.

Comment: You need to make sure that you correctly indicate which parts are copied. Why are you including a complete other answer that it longer than the answer you provided? Typically you would only do that to add to a point you’re making, not to add their point to your answer.

Answer (score 1):

"Potholes" come from the road surface deteriorating through traffic and weather. They're usually fairly shallow.

"Holes" in the road are usually dug intentionally by gas, water and other utility companies, and surrounded by cones or barriers. If dug in a long shape to take a pipe or cable it would be a "trench"